# How to get insights of the instagram's post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to get the insights of Instagram's post using media-id. From the URL e.g https://www.instagram.com/p/BWxFy1hHbzz I got the media-id "1563056029344578803" and owner-id "1371714791". But I could not fetch the insights as per the documentation i.e https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/. I am getting the response like

`{ "error": { "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 1563056029344578803", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 803, "fbtrace_id": "A16zgltTT2GbwICaeMXkIJT" } }`
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/1563056029344578803/insights?access_token=XXXXX&metric=follower_count,impressions,profile_views,reach&period=day

I have followed everything as per the documentation. Please give the follow-up for this issue.

Comment: So you are using a user token of the owner of that item, and it includes all the permissions mentioned under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#requirements?

Comment: Yes @CBroe, but no luck!